# Getting specific smtp address from proxy address attribute via powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to get only addresses starting with nby.

I have proxyAddresses for users like below.

```
sAMAccountName,ProxyAddresses
user01,SMTP:user01@domainA.com;smtp:user01@domainA.com;smtp:nby24048@domainA.com
user02,SMTP:user02@domainA.com;smtp:user02@domainA.com;smtp:nby44048@domainA.com
....
so on
```

script :

```
Get-Content "C:\Scripts\employeelist.txt" |
  ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(mail=$_)" -Properties * } |
  Select-Object sAMAccountName,mail,@{L = "ProxyAddresses"; E = { ($_.ProxyAddresses -match '^smtp:') -join ";"}} |
  Export-Csv "C:\Scripts\users-output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

My desired output:

```
sAMAccountName,ProxyAddresses
user01,nby24048@domainA.com
user02,nby44048@domainA.com
....
so on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input text file contains email adresses each on a separate line, you can do this:

```
# the Where-Object is just to make sure you don't read in blank lines
Get-Content -Path "C:\Scripts\employeelist.txt" | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' } | ForEach-Object { 
    Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(mail=$_)" -Properties ProxyAddresses |
    Select-Object SamAccountName,
                  @{Name = "ProxyAddresses"; Expression = { ($_.ProxyAddresses -match '^smtp:nby.+') -join ";"}}
} | Export-Csv "C:\Scripts\users-output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

P.S. Don't use `-Properties *` if you only want a few extra properties Get-ADUser does not already provide.